# Reference the second row in named table for data validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, validation

I have a named table in excel called "FINAL". I would like to create the drop down list from the second row of the table. I know that we can use `=FINAL[#Headers]` to create a list from the headers, but I need to create it from the second row in the table. of course I need it to be dynamic and use the table name since the table is going to change.

THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step1:**

Add named range `myList` with formula: `=INDEX(FINAL[#Data],2,0)`

[image]

**Step2:**

Select any cell and add data validation with *Source:* `=myList`

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know you have found a solution, but I would recommend using the Indirect function instead of creating an unnecessary named range.

You can't reference a table directly by name within the data validation formulas, but you can within the Indirect function, such as:

`=INDEX(INDIRECT("FINAL[#Data]"),2,0)`

This would provide you with the same list but without the need for a named range.

Comment: `Indirect` is a [volatile function](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) and your formula recalculates each time _any_ cell changed. This makes your wb very slow. I highly recommend you to avoid using volatile functions like `Indirect`, `Offset` and etc. if it's possible