# data validation - reference cells other cells in Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

So I have a data-validation sheet which I'm using as a drop down box.  The data validation has a visible field and 2 fields which need to be referenced (and x and y value)

So the range is this:

```
answer --- x --- y  
|          |     | 
YES ------ 3 --- 0
|          |     |
NO ------- 5 --- 1
```

How can I have the user select YES via a data-validation list and then reference 3 (the corresponding X value) on a different cell?

In MS Access, I would create a combobox and have Answer, x, y and have the visible columns be 1"; 0"; 0".  Then to reference the value, I'd use combobox.column(1).

I'm not sure how to reference that in Excel.

[image: Excel using data validation to reference other cells]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the validation cell as any other cell in your formulas. Therefore, you can do `If()` statements.  For example, in your cell B1, you can just do a formula: `=IF($A$1="Yes",3,IF($A$1="No",5,""))`.

If you have lots of possibilities, you can set up a vlookup table, and just put a vlookup formula in `B1`, using `A1` as the lookup value.

Comment: I'll take a look at setting it up like that. I saw this as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635194/reference-the-second-row-in-named-table-for-data-validation

Comment: not all of them will be binary.  I think there's a max of 5 options.

Comment: I used vLookup.  Thanks for the response.